# AWS ELB health check failing when trying to force HTTPS through NGINX for my single page application

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm trying to force https on my http endpoints using NGINX like so:

```
server {
    location / {
        root /data/www;
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
    }
    location /images/ {
        root /data;
    }
}
```

Note that all im serving from nginx are static files (an HTML file, javascript file, and a coupl

My ELB health check is hitting HTTP:80/. So what I think it's happening, is that ELB tries to ping my server, hits that rewrite, and gets returned a 301? I've seen a lot of answers for ruby and node, but this is just static assets. Help!

Answer (score 2):

Yep, ELB will hit your server via its IP (thus getting the default `server` block) and anything other than a 2xx request will be handled as a failure.

We use a default server block for ELB to ping:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    location = /status {
      return 200;
      access_log off;
    }
}
```

Comment: so your ELB is hitting `HTTP:80/status` ?

Comment: @jouerai Correct. Any other route hitting the IP directly gets a 404. All the other server blocks have a `server_name` directive.

Comment: so should this be my nginx's conf: https://gist.github.com/juhaelee/6b19abde2e5cd56d3572

Comment: @jouerai You'll want a `server_name` directive in the second block with the domain(s) your site runs on.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was doing a health check again TCP:80 not HTTP:80